# How to check a LatLong falls within the city bounds or not in Android App?

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I'm developing an app that capture user latitude and longitude.
The user will use PlaceAutocompleteFragment for searching a location.I need to find whether the searched location falls within the city bounds or not.Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: you can get the bounds of a city using the google maps  api

Comment: @akash93 there seems some problem with google api. It gives state name instead of city name for some places.

Comment: Just tried using reverse geocoding, and here's what I got: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true The city name can be found having `"types" : [ "locality", "political" ]`. So if there is no value `types` with values `[ "locality", "political" ]`, then it should not be in the city. Not sure that I'm right, but that's what I think

Comment: I'm using PlaceAutocompleteFragment for getting a location.I need to check the user location and drop location lies in city bounds.For some locations i'm getting the city name but for some locations only state name is available.

Comment: I guess if the bounds are not available then maybe you can use the `viewport` data as a secondary measure?